# Ruby - writing to a file while iterating in a class

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to write to a file while looping in Ruby? My code looks something like this:

navigator.rb

```
def launch_process
  while obj.present?
    return something while something_else
  end
end
```

app.rb # launcher

```
navigator = Navigator.new(args)
var = navigator.launch_process

$file = File.open("output.csv", "a+")
open($file, 'a+') { |file| file.write(var) } # won't work
```

The idea is to update the CSV file with data that is being gradually returned by the Navigator Object, launch_process method.

Comment: `CSV.open('output.csv', 'w') do |csv|
  var.each do |result|
    csv << result
  end
end`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example :

```
def launch_process(io)
  10.times do |i|
    sleep 1
    io.puts i
    ## Uncomment this line if you want to update the file during every iteration
    # io.flush
  end
end

f = File.open('output.csv','a+')
launch_process(f)
f.close
```

If you post more code it would be easier to adapt this loop to your example.